# Two separate click events on elements where second element is a child of first

Tags: jquery, dom-events

I want to distinguish my click event. I have a div structure which is like this :

```
<div class="image-entry select-image">
    <img src="http:myimage.jpg" />
    <a class="btn btn-danger deleteimages" href="javascript:;">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have to perform two different click events, one for class **select-image** and the other
for class **deleteimages**

I have the click event for class **select-image** working fine as it is sort of parent div
but when I try to fire the click event for class **deleteimages** then it fires click event proper but at the same time also fires the click event of **select-image** as it is the parent div.

How can I fire click events for these that they are independent of each other..??

Also I don't want to use inline function calling.
For example

```
<a onclick="myfunction();"></a>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yunus_Aslam/m321jg0w/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `event.stopPropagation()` To simply prevent the event from bubbling to ancestor elements.

like this:

```
$(".deleteimages").on('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation()
    //related code
})
```

[API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m321jg0w/1/)

Comment: Not working. Actually I tried this before for a long time and after I failed I posted my question here. I also tried e.preventDefault() as well..

Comment: Thanks this is now working.. Actually It was not working in my case because I have the elements created dynamically and I was using live click function. I have removed that with click function and that is working now.. Thanks for your help. Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
$(".deleteimages").click(function(event){
        alert('delete image click');
         return false;
});
```

Comment: Sandeep Pal, this will not work and I don't even want to try your way. It is not practical.

Comment: Sorry! if you dont find it practical but it's working on my side.

Comment: Try this 
Inside the click function of "image-entry" class, alert something..
Now when you click "deleteimages", it will first alert first from the parent class and then its own ..